# Custom ORM in .NET

Tags: .net, orm

I want to call only stored procedures on database and fill my C# object according to the result. I just need a mapping file, and a fast reflection tool like [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/) found on CodePlex to create my own ORM.

Is there any ORM available with these feature for C# which has lightning fast performance ?
or what should I do to complete the above scenario in terms of mapping database objects ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several implementations of .NET ORMs.

The framework already has two, Linq to Sql and Entity Framework.  What type of database are you trying to target?

If you are looking for open source implementations check out

[NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.com/)

I really wouldn't try building one yourself unless you have plenty of time!  Most ORMs have a huge feature list.

I have used a product called [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/default.aspx) from [Mindscape](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/). It support multiple rdbms, has a fantastic designer, superb linq capabilities and provides great performance.

Comment: +1 agreed; there are existing ORMs like NHibernate or Entity Framework that can call stored procedures just fine; don't recreate the wheel when there are great ones out there already

Comment: NHibernate and Entity Framework is very heavy but complete. there are several benchmarks out there that shows these frameworks has low performance compared to other available frameworks like DataObject.NET

Comment: LightSpeed is great and the performance section of this product is exactly what I'm looking for but i need an open source

Answer (score 0):

If you need fast read performance, use EF6.x and make sure you use AsNoTracking and also that you set up some additional values first. This will make it super-fast...but for the price that this supports just reading, so no change detection and no data-updates. This will make EF6x 5x faster than it's default behaviour, see [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/orm-read-performance-ef-vs-dapper-balazs-hideghety).

Also make sure you use database views, indexes to add extra speeds to all selects. But the best advice is: always check what code is sent to the database from the ORM layer, do eager-loading, use IQuery projections, ...

NHibernate is a fine tool too. I use it for my domain model where i handle all the changes.

Also here's another article of mine with the most common problems people have when using ORM inproperly (not using eager-load, etc.) - [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/get-know-your-orm-avoid-bad-habits-balazs-hideghety/). Also by profiling or eager load you can avoid N+1 select, by using views you can get additional speed...